# Wallet hash signing: how to recover the pair of Big Ints?

Tags: go-ethereum

The `Wallet` interface in `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/accounts.go:38` provides a method called

```
SignHash(account Account, hash []byte) ([]byte, error)
```

to sign a hash using the private key of an account. The signature is returned as an array of bytes.

However, the wallet contains an ECDSA key for that account and signing with ECDSA typically returns a pair of big.Ints (provided a rand) as implemented in https://golang.org/src/crypto/ecdsa/ecdsa.go?s=4459:4542#L141

How do I recover the two big.Ints from the bytes retuned from the `SignHash` method ?

Comment: From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/signature_nocgo.go#L55 the format is _The produced signature is in the [R || S || V] format where V is 0 or 1_

Comment: @Ismael you are right - see edit above - although it is not calling the code you mentioned AFAICT. Please create an answer from your comment so that I can award the response.

Comment: I've just put a link. Your solution is pretty nice and complete, plus you have done the hard work checking to ensure it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Ismael, it is in the R|S|V compact format.

As a proof, this works fine:

```
r := signature[0:32]
s := signature[32:64]
v := signature[64]

if !crypto.ValidateSignatureValues(v, new(big.Int).SetBytes(r),             new(big.Int).SetBytes(s), false) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Invalid signature format")
}

// v needs to be at the end for libsecp256k1
pubKeyBytes, err := crypto.Ecrecover(hash, signature)
```